# Move a fixed substring to the end of a filename when copying files

Tags: bash, shell, file

I have bunch of files in a folder having names that start with `MyTest`:

```
MyTestHttpAdaptor.class
MyTestJobCreation.class
```

I want to create copies of these files with names that remove the `MyTest` prefix, and add a `Test` suffix:

```
MyHttpAdaptorTest.class
MyJobCreationTest.class
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Do they all differ by just a number: 1, 2, 3 and so on?

Comment: "How do I do thing-X on UNIX?" is a better fit for our sister site [unix.se]. If you had a narrow question about an issue you encountered while writing a script to do this or another job, *that* could be topical here -- but if your *primary goal* is about copying files more than it is about software development, Stack Overflow is likely not to be the right place. (BTW, did you try looking for a pattern that does this using `mv`, and changing it to call `cp` instead?)

Comment: Numbers there are just illustrative to demonstrate different filenames. it is not a pattern there. Sorry for confusion

Comment: Would you mind showing some real examples then :) I will delete my answer for now since it won’t match an updated question.

Comment: for file in *
do
    cp $file  Test$file
done

Basic shell script tutorials: 

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-resource-for-learning-bash-scripting

Comment: Edited for better filenames

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes I've tried to find the answer and trust me I did search hard before posting question here.

Comment: ...so you want to move the name `Test` to the end of each filename (well, but before the extension)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for file in MyTest*.*; do    # iterate over files that start with MyTest and have a .
  ext=${file##*.}            # remove everything before the last . to get the extension
  basename=${file%.*}        # remove everything *after* the last . to get the "basename"
  new_basename=${basename#MyTest}      # remove the prefix to get the *new* basename
  new_file="${new_basename}Test.$ext"  # combine that prefix with the "Test" suffix & ext.
  [[ -e $new_file ]] || cp -- "$file" "$new_file"  # copy if result does not already exist
done
```

`${file##*.}`, `${file%.*}` and `${basename#MyTest}` are examples of [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe), removing prefixes and suffixes.